# Preview tab is disappeared in editor area of SpagoBI studio 5.2.0

Tags: business-intelligence, spagobi

I am using **SpagoBI Studio 5.2.0**. In this i have created a BIRT report as i want to see preview of my report i found that there is **no preview tab in editor area.**

Only i can see my report preview by going to *Run -> View Report -> Web viewer* or any other option.

Please suggest any setting for preview tab in SpagoBI Studio 5.2.0.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the preview tab was removed by Birt itself. So the only way to preview the report is the one that you are currently using with the Run menu.